# reading a plist-file into a NSDictionary using Swift 2 in iOS 9

Tags: nsdictionary, swift2, ios9

I have a defined a class that reads in a Dictionary from a file:

```
import Foundation
class Orte_c {
    var meineOrte = NSDictionary()

    init() {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("mySites",             ofType: "plist") {
        let x = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        meineOrte = x!
    }
}
} // end Orte_c
```

The plist-file was created by an objective-c app and is a dictionary where key and value are strings. This seems to work, but when I attempt to access the contents of this dictionary I get keys that read 
**Optional(mykeytext)**
instead of only **mykeytext** . When looking up the value corresponding to a key, I get **Optional(myvaluestring)** instead of only **myvaluestring**. Hence my question: How do I get rid of this Optional()-clause? Its definitely not in my plist-file.

```
@IBAction func meinTest(sender: AnyObject) {
    let x = mO.meineOrte    // mO is defined as var mO = Orte_c()
    print("x includes \(x.count) elements")
    var key: String; var vs: String;
    let enumerator: NSEnumerator = x.keyEnumerator()
    key = String(enumerator.nextObject())
    while key != "nil" {
        vs = String(x.valueForKey(key))
        print("key:" + key + " size:\(key.characters.count)" + " value:" + vs )
        key = String(enumerator.nextObject())
    }
}
```

The obvious would be to use key! and/or vs! - but this produces compilation errors.

Comment: Why enumerate the keys and then not use them to get the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift has more effective ways to enumerate a dictionary

```
let x = mO.meineOrte as! [String:String]  // mO is defined as var mO = Orte_c()
print("x includes \(x.count) elements")
for (key, value) in x {
  print("key:" + key + " value:" + value )
}
```

Comment: Thanks vadian - this helped. It works - although I do not currently grasp the syntax as used. I am learning....

Comment: From the Swift point of view `NSEnumerator` is a legacy class which should be replaced with the native Swift functions to enumerate collection types. Please read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105 for further details.